# How do I process an image using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**I have a picture.** It's a calligraphic letter.

[image: 1]

I need to make it filled with dots so that all the dots follow each other and correspond to the thickness of the letter line, that is, if the letter line becomes thicker, then the dot becomes larger. here is an example:

[image: 2]

(That's the letter it turns out to be)

I tried to work with the skeleton of a photo using OpenCV and Pillow, but nothing worked out, I will be very glad if you help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: distance transform might be a good starting point -- you really should [edit] your question's title to add some meaning

Comment: Your title absolutely sucks. Please change it to reflect what you're actually asking.

Comment: Title is a bit irrelevant here: there's no programming question, just a set of requirements. Off-topic as written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Played around a bit and arrived at this rather naive approach that looks to iteratively place dots and that seems to produce results somewhat in the direction of what I believe you are looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# read image into numpy array
img = np.asarray(Image.open('../zZfpE.jpg'))
# binarize and coarse-graining
img = (img[::2, ::2, 0] < 128).astype(int)

def make_dots(
    img, # 2d np array of 1s and 0s
    spd=25, # speed up factor
    marg=0.5, # minimum spacing between dots relative to dot size,
    max_ds=27, # maximum dot diameter in pixels
    min_ds=6, # minimum dot diameter in pixels    
):

    # start with blank image
    img2 = np.zeros(img.shape)
    h, w = img.shape

    # keep track of areas occupied by dots
    occ = set()
    
    ofs = int(spd ** 0.5)

    # iterate over dot sizes, decreasing
    for t in np.arange(max_ds, min_ds, -5):
        # iterate over pixels
        for i in range(0, h, ofs):
            for j in range(0, w, ofs):
                d = 0
                # increase dot diameter while 1. within bounds, b. corners of bounding box are black and 3. not already occupied
                while (
                    i + d < h and j + d < w
                ) and all(
                    [img[i + d, j + d], img[i, j + d], img[i + d, j]]
                ) and not any(
                    [(i + d1, j + d2) in occ for d1, d2 in [(0, d), (d, 0), (d, d)]]
                ):
                    d += 1
                # consider dot only if exceeding threshold
                if d > t:
                    m = int(marg * d)
                    ci = i + d // 2
                    cj = j + d // 2
                    d2 = (d//2) ** 2
                    # iterate over pixels in bounding box of dot + margin
                    for a in range(i-m, i+d+m):
                        for b in range(j-m, j+d+m):
                            # mark pixel as occupied by dot
                            occ.add((a, b))
                            # if within radius, draw to image
                            if (ci - a) ** 2 + (cj - b) ** 2 < d2:
                                img2[a, b] = 1
    return img2


plt.imshow(np.hstack((img, make_dots(img))), cmap='gray_r')
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: B]

While it's somewhat brittle / hacky, it (w/ tailoring of parameters to the data at hand, or a modified version of it) may still be useful and if not, at least serve as some inspiration hopefully, hence sharing here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I played with the parameters, it turned out to be almost perfect, I am very grateful to You!

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. The OP has literally provided nothing but a set of requirements. Your question doesn't actually *answer* any specific programming question.